# "Fatal error" in Sikuli, libs dir is not on system path

Tags: java, selenium, automation, sikuli

I am using sikuli for first time in eclipse. I imported sikuli script jar file into my project and I used screen and pattern classes.

I am getting below error

```
[error] ResourceLoaderBasic: checkLibsDir: libs dir is not on system path: D:\libs
[action] ResourceLoaderBasic: checkLibsDir: Please wait! Trying to add it to user's path
[info] runcmd: reg QUERY HKCU 
[info] runcmd: reg QUERY HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment /v PATH 
[error] ResourceLoaderBasic: checkLibsDir: Logout and Login again! (Since libs folder is in user's path, but not activated)
[error] Terminating SikuliX after a fatal error! Sorry, but it makes no sense to continue!
If you do not have any idea about the error cause or solution, run again
with a Debug level of 3. You might paste the output to the Q&A board.
```

Comment: **If you do not have any idea about the error cause or solution, run again
with a Debug level of 3**

Comment: Clearly you are missing `D:\libs`(as prompted in the error log) on your PATH. Google how to add a PATH entry if you don't know how to add it.

Comment: https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/258555

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to use Sikuli in Eclipse, importing the Jar will not be enough. If you want to have access to Sikuli API, you can use the following dependency:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
      <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Just get that into your maven pom together with whatever Selenium version you're using and here you go.