# Sikuli error - No valid libs path available until now

Tags: java, sikuli

I got the below error message after running the test case with Sikuli.

```
[error] ResourceLoaderBasic: check: No valid libs path available until now!
[action] ResourceLoaderBasic: check: Please wait! Trying to extract libs to jar parent folder: C:/Build/vcac-qe-tar/lib/
[error] ResourceLoaderBasic: checkLibsDir: libs dir is not on system path: C:\Build\vcac-qe-tar\lib\libs
[action] ResourceLoaderBasic: checkLibsDir: Please wait! Trying to add it to user's path
[info] runcmd: reg QUERY HKCU
[info] runcmd: reg QUERY HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment /v PATH
[info] runcmd: reg ADD HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment /v PATH /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /f /d C:\Build\vcac-qe-tar\lib\libs
[info] runcmd: reg QUERY HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment /v PATH
[error] ResourceLoaderBasic: checkLibsDir: Successfully added the libs folder to users PATH!
RESTART all processes/IDE's using Sikuli for new PATH to be used!/nFor usages from command line logout/login might be necessary!
[error] Terminating SikuliX after a fatal error! Sorry, but it makes no sense to continue!
If you do not have any idea about the error cause or solution, run again
with a Debug level of 3. You might paste the output to the Q&A board.
```

I got the few answers from SO and Official Sikuli Q&A forum. None of them are useful to me in my situation. Those solutions are useful to fix the above issue in my local setup. Once I moved it to the server, I can't apply the solution of restarting the machine (most of the members proposed this solution after getting the above error).

1. Do we have any solution without restarting the server after updating the path successfully?
2. Any other solution to avoid this error?
3. Is this issue is fixed in latest Sikuli version? (I'm using 1.0.1 version.)

See the posts on this same issue.

1. https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/237544
2. ["Fatal error" in Sikuli, libs dir is not on system path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37116191/fatal-error-in-sikuli-libs-dir-is-not-on-system-path)

**Update**:

I got the answers from RaiMan in Sikuli offical bug report tool. Attached the link to the bug. It will be useful to some one.

https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/444232

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library handling and more is completely revised in 1.1.1
So you should give it a try at least ;-)

Comment: You mean that this issue is fixed in the latest versions of Sikuli. Please confirm it.